# Help understanding java algorithm using arraycopy to remove duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Im having difficulty understanding how the array is being copied in this algorithm. Im am fine with the code till i get to line 12 shown below. This code was from a book Im currently studying.
Im just trying to understand how the copy is carried out on each match

Wrote some values to simulate the a scenario

```
a = [10,4,6,10,5,2]

a[0] = a[3] MATCH occurs when j=3 

arraycopy(a, 4, a, 3, (5-3)) // Variable values substituted into arraycopy. (pretty sure they're correct)            

System.arraycopy(a, j+1, a, 0, n-j); // Line 12
```

The whole code:

```
    int n = a.length;

    if (n < 2){
        System.out.println("no duplicates");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i< n-1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
            if(a[i] == a[j]){
                --n;                    
                System.arraycopy(a, j+1, a, 0, n-j); // Line 12   
                --j;                    


                System.out.println();
            }
    int[] aa = new int[n];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, aa, 0, n);
```

Just for the record I understand the second arraycopy statement since its just a straightforward copy into array aa.

I know there are many arraycopy questions on SO but the ones i encountered did not answer this specific question because i need an step-through understanding of how the copying occurs match by match.

Anyway thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What is the algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: its supposed to remove the duplicate numbers from an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's a bug in the algorithm, since the first array copy will overwrite good data at the front of the array. I think the line should be:

```
System.arraycopy(a, j+1, a, j, n-j); // Line 12
```

This would shift the end of the array over one, overwriting only the one duplicate that was just found.

Right now, it works like this:

```
Before copy:
 i           j     n
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6]
                \  /
                n-j

After copy:
 i        j     n
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6]
```

Clearly wrong. There are now *more* duplicates than when we started!

With the updated line, it looks like this:

```
After copy:
 i        j     n
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

Much better. The duplicate 1 is gone.

As an additional note, this is a pretty horrible way to eliminate duplicates from an array. An array that was *all* duplicates would perform (n * (n - 1) / 2) element copies, which is ludicrous. The standard simple way to dedupe an array is usually to add each element to a `HashSet`, then iterate that set's contents into a new array.

Comment: Hi diev your right. i was just about to post a comment to @kal asking if i could get a second opinion on the parameters going into my arraycopy method because i felt like you said that "good data was being overwritten". then SO froze on me. Thank u very much diev. I spent so long trying to get it to semantically tick in my head.

Comment: Glad I could help! I added a quick note in my answer about a better way to remove duplicates from an array if you're interested.

Comment: hey @diev. just had a look again at your last 'after copy' explanation which in the array still contains duplicates. its look like a innocent typo.

Comment: Sorry, I shoud elaborate. The '6' is now techincally "duplicated" in the array, but it's not for the purposes of the algorithm. Part of the copy involves reducing `n` by 1. Since `n` is the eventual size of the new array, anything that's after the current value of `n` is effectively gone from the array.